# Mobile navigation menu move all page?

Tags: html, css, mobile, media-queries, navbar

anyone can help me create a menu that works like this on this page:https://www.cabinet-maker.co.uk/  for mobile.
I mean menu buttons and search, I really like it but I do not know how to create one, I'm new and I wanted to create one in my own blog.

Comment: You could try this plugin: https://grubersjoe.github.io/slide-menu/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a plugin, you can use plain JavaScript. I made a quick fiddle of it here:

https://jsfiddle.net/rajoh4bp/8/

```
Hover Over The Retail Navigation Bar Option Once You Are There.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of the jQuery plugins. For example https://mmenujs.com/ or https://corenav.com/index.html. Actually, there are a lot of menus, just google them and choose one of your favorite.

Answer (score 0):

You can make some fancy css3 menus by starting from nothing. You can add javascript or not.

[Even w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_mobile_navbar.asp) have a cool little tutorial about mobile menus :)

The most important thing to learn in webdesign is the vocabulary, so you can make efficient searches queries and find immediately what your are searching for.

For this request, the important words are "menu" and "slide". And you find [another w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_sidenav.asp) tutorial :)